# Plottng a graph for multiple attributes + matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data in following fashion:

```
efficiency = [{'weights': '25', 'sets': '5', 'time': '8.48', 'machine': 'a'},
 {'weights': '100', 'sets': '25', 'time': '7.43', 'machine': 'a'},
 {'weights': '25', 'sets': '5', 'time': '8.70', 'machine': 'b'},
 {'weights': '100', 'sets': '25', 'time': '7.73', 'machine': 'b'},
 {'weights': '25', 'sets': '5', 'time': '7.14', 'machine': 'c'},
 {'weights': '100', 'sets': '25', 'time': '8.38', 'machine': 'c'},
 {'weights': '25', 'sets': '5', 'time': '6.11', 'machine': 'd'}...]
```

It denotes time required in minutes for a machine to achieve the task with given weights and sets.

I am new to `matplotlib` so not getting how to plot a graph along the X and Y axis as shown in this  plot [image: Graph].

Its not necessary that graph should be similar to this graph. Please suggest any graph which should represent the time required for a machine,

Basically, 
I want to denote `time` required for a `machine` for the given `weights` and `sets`. I am not getting how to represent the features(time, machine, weights and sets)

Comment: I don't think it's obvious how the data you show would relate to a plot like the one in the image. How do you imagine your resulting plot to look like?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest -  Its not necessary it should be similar to the graph. Please suggest any graph which should represent the time required.

Comment: I cannot suggest anything. You need to tell us what you want to achieve. We can then help you with the technical aspect on how the code should look like.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I want to see a representation which should display `time` required(may be on Y axis) against  `Machine` (may be on X axis).

Comment: it's like the sampling is in serial mode; the time of sample doesn't coincide?

Comment: @Hamidreza - Basically - I want to show how efficient the machine is? Any idea how can I represent it?

Comment: @Laxmikant ok, there are lots of way, first I wanted to know if the efficiency is variable with time , speed or etc.?

Comment: @Hamidreza - Time

Comment: I suggest a line plot like you did, I'll answer in a minute...

Comment: @Hamidreza - Thank you very much, You can change the numbers from the dataset if required, as it is a client data so modified the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that data is time variable, a line plot suits it the best.

Honestly I'd do some pre-elaboration on dataset if I were you, this thing you need can be done very simple; create a Timestamp array separately and some array for each machine. However I don't know how much you are restricted to keep in the data as it is.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd


efficiency = [{'weights': '21', 'sets': '5', 'time': '1', 'machine': 'a'}, 
{'weights': '93', 'sets': '25', 'time': '2', 'machine': 'a'},
{'weights': '53', 'sets': '5', 'time': '1', 'machine': 'b'},
{'weights': '61', 'sets': '25', 'time': '2', 'machine': 'b'},
{'weights': '66', 'sets': '5', 'time': '1', 'machine': 'c'},
{'weights': '90', 'sets': '25', 'time': '2', 'machine': 'c'},
{'weights': '79', 'sets': '5', 'time': '1', 'machine': 'd'},
{'weights': '100', 'sets': '25', 'time': '1', 'machine': 'd'}]



class Efficiency:
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,6)
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.machines = []
        self.Timestamp = []
        for i in data:
            setattr(self, 'machine_'+i['machine'], dict(efficiency=[]))
            if not i['machine'] in self.machines: self.machines.append(i['machine'])
            if not i['time'] in self.Timestamp: self.Timestamp.append(i['time'])

    def readData(self):
        for i in self.data:
            getattr(self, 'machine_' + i['machine'])['efficiency'].append(float(i['weights']))

    def plotData(self):
        eff_dict = {}
        for i in self.machines:
            eff_dict['machine ' + i] = getattr(self, 'machine_' + i)['efficiency']
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(eff_dict, index= self.Timestamp)

        self.df.plot()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xticks(fontsize=12, rotation=90)
        plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
        plt.legend(fontsize=12)
        plt.tight_layout()

        plt.show()
        print(self.df)

test = Efficiency(efficiency)
test.readData()
test.plotData()
```

this is from your exact code;
[image]

If data can be defined like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

efficiency2 = [{'weights': np.random.uniform(60,100, 10),'sets':np.random.randint(5,25, 10), 'time': np.arange(0,10,1), 'machine': 'a'},\
{'weights': np.random.uniform(60,100, 10), 'sets': np.random.randint(5,25, 10), 'time': np.arange(0,10,1), 'machine': 'b'}]



class Efficiency:
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,6)
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.machines = []
        self.Timestamp = []
        for i in data:
            setattr(self, 'machine_'+i['machine'], dict(weight=i['weights'], sets = i['sets']))
            if not i['machine'] in self.machines: self.machines.append(i['machine'])
        self.Timestamp = data[0]['time']


    def plotData(self):
        weight_dict = {}
        for i in self.machines:
            weight_dict['machine ' + i + ' weight'] = getattr(self, 'machine_' + i)['weight']
            weight_dict['machine ' + i + ' sets'] = getattr(self, 'machine_' + i)['sets']
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(weight_dict, index= self.Timestamp)

        self.df.plot()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xticks(fontsize=12, rotation=90)
        plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
        plt.legend(fontsize=20)
        plt.ylabel('(%)',fontsize=20)
        plt.xlabel('time',fontsize=20)

        plt.show()
        print(self.df)

test = Efficiency(efficiency2)
test.plotData()
```

You will get this:
[image]

You can have two y label, desired `x_axis` format and various properties, it depends on how you like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The data looks like it would be well represented with a bar plot, where time is shown on the y axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(efficiency) # efficiency as defined in the question
df["time"] = df["time"].astype(float)
piv = df.pivot(columns="machine", index="weights", values="time")
piv.plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]

or ordered by machines,

```
piv = df.pivot(columns="weights", index="machine", values="time")
piv.plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]